# Call database using edit text [android]

Tags: android, database

By any change is their a way to call a database using edit text box. 
for example :
theirs a edit text and a button [search] when the user type a letter [example: a or b] then a list view will show some data

Answer (score 0):

**first** use searchView like this

```
SearchView sv=(SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
 sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
              //when the text change
              search(s);
                return false;
            }
        });
        sv.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() { 
//when canceling the search 
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**after that** the search function should be like this

```
  public void Rechercher(String name) {//button de recherche
    Cursor medecin = MainActivity.db.lireMedecin();
    medecinItems.clear();
    while (medecin.getPosition() < medecin.getCount()) {
         if ((medecin.getString(1).toUpperCase().contains(name.toUpperCase())) || (medecin.getString(2).toUpperCase().contains(name.toUpperCase()))
                || (((medecin.getString(1) + " " + (medecin.getString(2))).toUpperCase().contains(name.toUpperCase())))) {
             MedecinItem m=new MedecinItem(medecin.getString(0),medecin.getString(1) + " " + medecin.getString(2),medecin.getString(4),medecin.getString(3),medecin.getString(7));
             medecinItems.add(m);
        }
        medecin.moveToNext();
    }
    MedecinListAdapter mla=new MedecinListAdapter(MainActivity.this,medecinItems);
    ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView)).setAdapter(mla);
    ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView)).setOnScrollListener(ScrollList);
}
```

to now more about android database and cursors here are some tutorials :
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm
Now you now how to start